# How can I get data of different types from an anonymous class

Tags: java, arrays, oop, coding-style, buffer

I have an object that delegates some work to another object which is implementing an interface. Then, I am creating anonymous classes implementing this interface and I would like to get information from these.

Is it okay to use a final array with a size of one as a pointer to a primitve to share data with the anonymous class?

Here is a working example of what I mean :

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public static final int INVALID_VALUE = -1;

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {       
        final int[] buffer = { INVALID_VALUE }; // buffer is created
        final InterfaceA iaObject = new InterfaceA()
        {
            @Override
            public void doStuff(final String paramA)
            {
                buffer[0] = paramA.length(); // buffer is filled in anonymous class
            }
        };

        final ClassA objA = new ClassA(iaObject);
        objA.doStuff("hello, world");

        if (buffer[0] == INVALID_VALUE) // buffer is used
        {
            System.err.println("Invalid length !");
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.println("The length is : " + Integer.toString(buffer[0]));
        }
    }

    public static class ClassA
    {
        private final InterfaceA iaObject;

        public ClassA(final InterfaceA iaObject)
        {
            this.iaObject = iaObject;
        }

        public void doStuff(final String paramA)
        {
            this.iaObject.doStuff(paramA);
        }
    }

    public static interface InterfaceA
    {
        void doStuff(String paramA);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not have doStuff return an int instead?

Comment: You should use an int instead of an array, since you are using only one position

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot `doStuff` does not return an int because I sometimes need a boolean, a String, and other types of values.

Comment: @DanielPereira I must use an array because I cannot refer to a non-final variable inside the anonymous class.

Comment: So you want to have a function that can do literally anything, and on the fly also update some global variables? That smells like bad code design.

Comment: @Heuster - I might go so far as to call it Sourcery

Comment: @Heuster The `doStuff` method is an example. The question behind it is  "how can i get data (of different types) from anonymous classes"

Comment: @JesanFafon I am using an array with a size of one as a pointer to the integer. I wouldn't have to do this with an object.

Comment: You could always use an Integer if that is the case. The Java roadmap has primitives being removed in the future anyway ;)

Comment: @JesanFafon Integers are not mutable, I'd have to create my own mutable wrapper for all primitives.

Comment: This is correct. However, all of the normal operations of the primitive types also work on their wrappers (they auto-box and unbox). This is why I can say Integer A = 32; Integer B = 32; System.out.println(A + B); and get 64. Wrapper types in Java behave like the primitive with extra convenience methods and the benefits of being reference based instead of value based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: why not using a generic for an out parameter?

```
interface InterfaceA {

   public <T> void doStuff( String paramA, Holder<T> holder );
}

class Holder<T> {

    public T t;
}
```

Full example:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
   public static final int INVALID_VALUE = -1;

   public static void main(final String[] args)
   {       
      final InterfaceA< Integer > iaObject = new InterfaceA< Integer >() {
         @Override
         public Integer doStuff( String paramA, Holder<Integer> holder ) {
            return holder.value = paramA.length();
         }
      };

      final ClassA<Integer> objA = new ClassA<>( iaObject );
      int result = objA.doStuff("hello, world", new Holder<>( INVALID_VALUE ));
      if( result == INVALID_VALUE ) {
         System.err.println("Invalid length !");
      }
      else {
         System.err.println("The length is : " + Integer.toString( result ));
      }
   }

   public static class ClassA<T> {
      private final InterfaceA<T> iaObject;

      public ClassA( final InterfaceA<T> iaObject_ ) {
         this.iaObject = iaObject_;
      }

      public T doStuff( final String paramA, Holder<T> holder ) {
         return this.iaObject.doStuff( paramA, holder );
      }
   }

   public static interface InterfaceA<T> {
      public T doStuff( String paramA, Holder<T> resultHolder );
   }

   public static class Holder<T> {

      public T value;

      public Holder( T value_ ) {
         value = value_;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have made the interface an abstract generic class with a getter and a setter for the value.

Comment: Thanks for the full example, but I cannot modify the structure of `ClassA`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the gist of your question, you're wondering if it is good design principle to use a final array as a wrapper to share memory between an anonymous inner class and its enclosing class.

In my experience, this is a pretty poor way of sharing data between two objects. It is probably wiser to declare your interface differently. Either return an object or use a generic to specify what type you expect back from your anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the largest problems with your approach is the lack of encapsulation - your InterfaceA implementation uses some "global" data holder (the array), and there is no way to prevent that this array can be used elsewhere, which in turn could lead to all kinds of problems (race conditions or whatever).

A cleaner way would be the definition of some separate class (or interface) with a getInt()-method or something similar.